# java regex how to match some string that is not some substring

Tags: java, regex

For example, my org string is:

```
CCC=123
CCC=DDDDD
CCC=EE
CCC=123
CCC=FFFF
```

I want everything that does not equal to "CCC=123" to be changed to "CCC=AAA"

So the result is:

```
CCC=123
CCC=AAA
CCC=AAA
CCC=123
CCC=AAA
```

How to do it in regex?

If I want everything that is equal to "CCC=123" to be changed to "CCC=AAA", it is easy to implement:

(AAA[ \t]*=)(123)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    String foo = "CCC=123 CCC=DDD CCC=EEE";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(CCC=(?!123).{3})");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(foo);
    String result = m.replaceAll("CCC=AAA");

    System.out.println(result);

}
```

output:

> CCC=123 CCC=AAA CCC=AAA

These are *zero-width, non capturing*, which is why you have to then add the `.{3}` to capture the non-matching characters to be replaced.

Comment: Can you tell me what .{3} means?

Comment: `.` means any character, `{3}` means three of them.

Comment: Erm, well, then you'd need to *change* that part to match whatever it is that *isn't* `123`.  The negative lookahead tells you that the three characters following `CCC=` are not `123`. Because you want to do a replace, you then need to supply a regex that matches whatever that is.

Comment: For example, it seems you have newlines separating the pairs ... `(CCC=(?!123)[^\n]+)` would work.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = s.replaceAll("(?m)^CCC=(?!123$).*$", "CCC=AAA");
```

`(?m)` activates MULTILINE mode, which allows `^` and `$` to match the beginning and and end of lines, respectively.  The `$` in the lookahead makes sure you don't skip something that matches only partially, like `CCC=12345`.  The `$` at the very end isn't really necessary, since the `.*` will consume the rest of the line in any case, but it helps communicate your intent.

Comment: It seems to be working as well. Can you tell me what is the differences between (CCC=(?!123$)[^\n]*) and (CCC=(?!123$).*)

Comment: In most regex flavors they would be identical; `.` matches any single character except a linefeed (`\n`).  However, Java is smarter about [line terminators](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lt) than most flavors.  The lines in your input could be separated by `\n` or `\r\n` or `\u2028`, and `^.*$` would still match them correctly.